# Number of stops an elevator will make

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

For $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(10)$, assume $Y$ people get into an elevator on the ground floor. There are $n$ floors above the ground floor, and everyone is equally likely to get out on any of them, and their choice when to get out is independent of each other. I want to compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$ where $X$ is the number of stops the elevator makes. I know the answer should be $n - ne^{-10/n}$.

This is what I have done so far: let $X_i$ be IRV for stop on the $i$th floor so that $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb E[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \mid Y]] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[\mathbb E[X_i \mid Y]] = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{y=0}^\infty \textbf P[X_i = 1 \mid Y = y] \; \textbf P[Y = y] = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{y=0}^\infty \textbf (1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n})^y) \frac{e^{-10} 10^y}{y!}$

This is as far as I got, but I don't know how to finish evaluating this sum and I'm concerned that it doesnt look like it is even going to come out to the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$S=\sum_{y=0}^\infty(n^y-(n-1)^y)\dfrac{e^{-10}(\dfrac{10}{n})^y}{y!}$$ is what you first need to find.

Break it up as $$S=\sum_{y=0}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-10}10^y}{y!}-e^{-10+\dfrac{10(n-1)}{n}}\sum_{y=0}^\infty\dfrac{(\dfrac{10(n-1)}{n})^ye^{-\dfrac{10(n-1)}{n}}}{y!}=1-e^{-\dfrac{10}{n}}$$

Then, $$E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^nS=nS=n-ne^{-\dfrac{10}{n}}$$

Good job by the way!